# No output and not worked When I run [Artisan::call(...)] or [shell_exec(...)] in phpunit test, but when not in phpunit, it is ok

Tags: php, phpunit, lumen, laravel-artisan

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function xxx()
{
   $exitCode = Artisan::call('queue:work');
   //shell_exec('php artisan queue:work');
}
```

Run `Artisan::call(...)` or `shell_exec(...)` in PHPUnit test, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

For your unit tests you don't use your normal laravel queue like you do in the rest of your project.

Start your queue using [`Queue::fake();`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#queue-fake) and then apply your test logic.

Your tests will push events in this queue and the mock workers will pick up.

Read more about mocking methods [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking).